# image loading is not working properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to display image through online URL path in react ,if I try to do that code its not working

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Dropdown() {
return (
    <div>
    <img alt="picture"src="https://pixabay.com/photos/strawberries-fruit-season-eating-3359755/" 
    height={200} width={200}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with this code , the url is not an image url please check with this url :
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/29/11/54/strawberries-3359755_960_720.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' just that your source image is wrong. Try this:

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Dropdown() {
return (
    <div>
    <img alt="picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/29/11/54/strawberries-3359755_960_720.jpg" height={200} width={200}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes now its working

Answer (score 1):

Your source image link is invalid..

change to this:
`<img alt="picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/29/11/54/strawberries-3359755_960_720.jpg" height={200} width={200}/>`

Comment: yes now its working